# Обращение ваш или Ваш

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Часто в официальной переписке читаю: "...учитывая Ваше мнение..." или "...рассматривая Ваше заявление..." или "...найден Ваш чемодан..." и т.п. Но здесь речь идёт о "мнении", "заявлении" и "чемодане". Уместно ли в данном контексте писать ВАШЕ с прописной буквы. Как-то уж очень подобострастно обращаться к чемодану на Вы (если это не чемодан Начальника).

Answer (score 3):

С чего бы это уважение путать с подобострастностью?
С заглавной Вы, Ваш и т.д. пишутся в зависимости не от того, кому пишется, а от степени официальности документа. В вашем случае, поскольку речь идёт о письменных документах и  обращении к одному лицу "Ваш" вполне уместно. При обращении к одному лицу вы со строчной используется при передачи устной речи или текстах её подменяющих (в чате, на форумах и т.п.).

Answer (score 1):

При этом, я часто сталкиваюсь с тем, что люди в диалогах тоже пишут "Вы" с большой буквы. А это неправильно. "Вы" пишется с большой буквы только при обращении к конкретному, причем одному лицу. В диалогах же (когда, например, разговаривают для литературных персонажа), а также при обращении к группе лиц "вы" пишется со строчной буквы.

Answer (score 0):

Следуя правилам этикета, к незнакомому человеку нужно обращаться на "Вы". В предложении "Найден Ваш чемодан" притяжательное местоимение "Ваш" образовано от личного местоимения "Вы", так как обращаются к незнакомому человеку. Поэтому местоимение "Ваш" здесь вполне уместно.